# java library similar to c++ map

Tags: java, c++, stl, hashmap

To find nth fibonacci number using memoization I found one code which uses `map` in c++.

I have tried to convert this code in java but it fails  .

**code in c++:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>   

typedef long long int ll;  

map<ll, ll> mp;  
ll M = 1000000007;       

long long fibonacci(long long n) {  
   if (mp.count(n))return mp[n];  
   long long k=n/2;  
   if (n%2==0) {   
      return mp[n] = fibonacci(k)*(fibonacci(k+1)+fibonacci(k-1)) % M;  
    } else {   
       return mp[n] = (fibonacci(k+1)*fibonacci(k+1) + fibonacci(k)*fibonacci(k)) % M;  
    }  
 }  

 int main()  
{  
   mp[0]=mp[1]=1;  
   ll t;  
   scanf("%lld",&t);
   printf("%lld\n",fibonacci(t));  
}
```

I have tried same code in java using `HashMap`.

**code in java:**

```
static HashMap<Long,Long> hm=new HashMap<Long,Long>();

static long  f(long n) {
  if (hm.containsKey(n)) return hm.get(n);
  long k=n/2;
  if (n%2==0) {
     return hm.put(n,f(k)*(f(k+1)+f(k-1)) % M);        
  } else { 
     return hm.put(n, (f(k+1)*f(k+1) + f(k)*f(k)) % M);
   }
 }



  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    hm.put(1L,1L);
    hm.put(0L,1L);
    long b=f(2L);
  }
```

but this code in java gives `StackOverflowError`.

I have tried this code using `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` in java both gives same error.

Which class I have to use which works same as `map` in c++?

Please someone explain how `map` work in c++.

**EDIT**
look at the output of code in `java` and `c++`
c++: [c++ code](http://ideone.com/rTjjw6)
java: [java code](https://ideone.com/Yt59Pb)

Comment: That is a really complicated way to implement this.  Why not have a loop to record all the values which fit into a `long` in an array. It will take 3 ms and be not only faster but much simpler.

Comment: i am solving this question http://www.spoj.com/problems/POWFIB/

Comment: I have tried using matrix multiplication but it gives time limit exceed

Answer (score 2):

To memorize all the possible fibonacci numbers which fit into a `long` you can use a simple array.

```
static final int[] FIB = new int[100_000_000];
static final intM = 1000000007;

static {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    FIB[1] = FIB[2] = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i < FIB.length; i++) {
        int l = FIB[i - 1] + FIB[i - 2];
        while (l >= M)
            l -= M;
        FIB[i] = l;
    }
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to build table of %,d fibonacci values%n", time/1e3, FIB.length);
}

public static long fibonacci(int n) {
    return FIB[n];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.648 seconds to build table of 100,000,000 fibonacci values
```

This would use 400 MB of memory for the array which is more efficient than any map implementation.

Comment: input is in range of 10^8

Comment: and number of test cases are around 10^5

Comment: @priyank in that case you need to calculate the value using a formula.  https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.4-5.shtml There isn't enough memory to memorize that many values. BTW `long` won't store results above fib(92).

Comment: question is to find nth fibinacci number mod 10^9+7. I have used %M in solution

Comment: @priyank the number of digits in fib(10^8) is approximately `20,898,764` so to memorize all these values you need approx 10^8 * 4 MB on average or 4 * 10 ^ 14 bytes or 400 TB.

Comment: @priyank In that case you need 8 * 10^8 bytes or 800 MB as a `long[]` to store all the possible calculated Fibonacci values.  This is far more practical.

Comment: look at this solution http://ideone.com/sFrFVl   I am trying to convert it into java but not able to convert function f() in java due to above mention problem

Comment: @priyank see my solution which memorizes every possible value in 0.7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A [`StackOverflowError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) happens when you have too many methods calls stacked, it's thrown by the virtual machine. It's not a `HashMap` problem at all.

From the docs:

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses
>   too deeply.

You could either increase the stack size of your JVM by using the [`-Xss`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967885/jvm-option-xss-what-does-it-do-exactly) flag, or you could try to use a better algorithm, or review this one to check if it's really equivalent to the c++ version... But either way, I think you're just overcomplicating this, there are simpler ways of getting the same result.

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965006/java-recursive-fibonacci-sequence) on how a recursive fibonacci method looks like.

---

**EDIT:** Check [this link](http://java67.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/java-program-fibonacci-series-with.html), it shows how you can get the nth number using memoization and Java.

Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n), there are lots of answers with different methods on how to get a large nth fibonacci number.

---

**Another way of doing this**

Use a `List<Long>` as a cache.

```
private static List<Long> cache = new ArrayList<Long>();

/*
 * Java Program to calculate Fibonacci numbers with memorization
 * This is quite fast as compared to previous Fibonacci function
 * especially for calculating factorial of large numbers.
 */
public static int improvedFibo(int number){
    Integer fibonacci = cache.get(number);
    if(fibonacci != null){
        return fibonacci; //fibonacci number from cache
    }
    //fibonacci number not in cache, calculating it
    fibonacci = fibonacci2(number);

    //putting fibonacci number in cache for future request 
    cache.put(number, fibonacci); 
    return fibonacci;
}
```

[Taken from here.](http://java67.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/java-program-fibonacci-series-with.html)

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875380/recursive-fibonacci-memoization) for another example.

Comment: I think problem is map in c++ works different than Hashmap in java. I am novice to c++ so i dont know how map in c++ works

Comment: And **stackoverflowerror** is  because of calling f(k+1) every time while in c++ code it doesn't give same error .. I dont understand why this happens in c++

Comment: I believe that the only difference is that c++ `map` uses less memory than Java `HashMap`.

Comment: look at this c++ implementation http://ideone.com/rTjjw6 . here printf in function is for debugging purpose .. it calls function two time only :)

Comment: while same function in java https://ideone.com/Yt59Pb continuesly calls it self for n=2