# Recursive Fibonacci evaluation not terminating for N=100

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I wrote this method that finds the nth term of the fibonacci sequence, and it works perfectly fine if you put in number like 10, but if the number gets bigger for example 100, the console window won't even show up. Does this have to do with the maximum size of an int? Or maybe a problem with the stack size? I don't care about negatives I'll deal with that later. But what is the problem with my code?

```
public static int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, integer overflow is a problem, but it does not affect runtime. Calculating fibonacci numbers without a cache is very computationally intensive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Call stack size is the most significant factor for the run time of this. Look into memoization at this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875380/recursive-fibonacci-memoization

Comment: Recursive Fibonacci evaluation becomes unusably slow somewhere around 45. Use an iterative method, or memorization.

Comment: Or, use the "closed form" to calculate it based on the golden ratio.

Comment: Poor title. The title should express something about the problem, not just your helplessness.