# How to useCallback in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am curious about the difference between `useEffect` and `useCallback`.

```js
const onUpdate = useCallback(() => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('answer')
    .where('questionUid', '==', questionUid)
    .get()
    .then((snap) => {
      const answer = snap.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setAnswers(answer);
    });
}, [answers]);
```

Comment: I had the same doubt today morning and read this article...this explains quite clearly. https://medium.com/@infinitypaul/reactjs-useeffect-usecallback-simplified-91e69fb0e7a3. Hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use useCallback, useMemo and useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910036/when-to-use-usecallback-usememo-and-useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

They are two complete different things: the aim of `useEffect()` is to run side effects after the component has rendered, while `useCallback()` aim is to memoize a callback function so that it is not re-instantiated every time the component re-renders.

`useEffect()` can trigger a component re-render and somehow change what the user sees in the interface, either in terms of layout (e.g. resizing an image in response to a viewport change) or in terms of content (e.g. retrieving data from an external resource) while `useCallback()` is a performance optimization with no evident effect for the user (well, actually in some cases forgetting to use `useCallback()` might lead to an infinite re-render loop but that is a different topic).