# ReactJs state inside of nested function is not being updated, but it is updated outside(in fucntional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to send get requests at certain interval using setInterval. So my script looks like that:

```
const [package_id, setPackageId] = useState({id: 1, result: NaN})

async function get_images(detail_id){ 
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_images', {params: {detail_id}, headers:{
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0',
      }}).then((res) =>{

        ... // some processing

        setPackageId(prevstate => {return {...prevstate, id :prevstate.id + 1}})
        
    }
    ).catch(errs => {
        console.log(errs)
    })
}
useEffect(() => {
    const request_interval = setInterval(get_images, 2000, package_id.id)
    return () => clearInterval(request_interval);
}, [])
```

Even though state package_id.id is being updated(I checked using useEffect). In get_images function, it's value is always the same. How can I use updated value of state?

PS: I also tried to access state inside of function(without passing argument (detail_id)), but it didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass package_id.id through setInterval
But you didn't add package_id.id as a dependency in the useEffect
so you're passing the same id every time
because the effect here doesn't listen to the id updates
But if you add package_id.id as a dependency
the effect will keep listening for id updates and the effect will keep getting triggered
So you can try this
I hope this will help you

```js
const [package_id, setPackageId] = useState({id: 1, result: NaN})

const get_images = useCallback(async () =>{
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_images', {params: {package_id.id}, headers:{
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0',
    }}).then((res) =>{
        ... // some processing
        setPackageId(prevstate => ({...prevstate, id :prevstate.id + 1}))
        
    }).catch(errs => {
        console.log(errs)
    })
}, [package_id])
useEffect(() => {
    const request_interval = setInterval(get_images, 2000)
    return () => clearInterval(request_interval);
}, [get_images])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It did work. I didn't know that useEffect dependencies can accept functions. How do they monitor if that function changes/updates?

Comment: @DastanZhumazhanov https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback          You can read the explanation in the official documentation
The documentation explains in detail the mechanism of its operation

Comment: @DastanZhumazhanov https://infinitypaul.medium.com/reactjs-useeffect-usecallback-simplified-91e69fb0e7a3  I think I may not have understood your question correctly at first, you can take a look at this article, which explains useEffect and why to use useCallback

Comment: @DastanZhumazhanov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910036/when-to-use-usecallback-usememo-and-useeffect This discussion I think should also help you better understand the use of the react hook

Comment: thank you for the provided references. It helps a lot.